# Complex code inside ember Route

Tags: ember.js

I have the Route

```
App.MyRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model : function() {
        return complexCode();
    }
}
```

complexCode makes many asynchronous chained calls that depend of the above results. 
for this reason I want complexCode is distributed into several files for easier maintenance of the code. 
The problem I have is that when I'm in a method of another file I have no access to MyRoute.

One option is to pass the object as parameter but I want to avoid having to pass the object by all methods.

```
App.MyRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model : function() {
        var route = this;
        return complexCode(route);
    }
```

What is the best way to have gloal access a property or method of MyRoute?
It's ok the approach of separate the code in other files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's probably a bad pattern to use.  It tightly couples your `complexCode` to the route.  You'd be better off passing in the necessary values to execute the complex code, or creating a mixin and adding it to each route (this would then allow you to have methods that are within the scope of the route).

http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Mixin.html

Comment: it's ok keep the "code in separate files"?
what can i do if i need global access to some object in ember?
Thank you!